# Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialized value(s) with strcat in for loop

Tags: c++, c, malloc, valgrind

I have a file containing the strings of 3 chromosome, which I want to concatenate into one genome. And then I have to access this concatenated string across multiple threads (I use pthread_t). To to this I have to use pthread_mutex_lock when extracting the data, then I use strcat to concatenate the data which are extracted using the function fai_fetch using const char* and then I am saving the data as a char* (see below).

```
// genome_size the size of all the chromosomes together
// chr_total the number of chromosomes I wish to concatenate
char* genome = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (genome_size+chr_total));

for (int i = 0; i < chr_total; i++){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&data_mutex);
    const char *data = fai_fetch(seq_ref,chr_names[i],&chr_sizes[i]);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&data_mutex);
    //sprintf(&genome[strlen(genome)],data);
    strcat(genome,data);  
    //sprintf(genome+strlen(genome),data); //All three gives conditional jump or move error

    //sprintf(genome,data); // THIS SOLVES VALGRIND ISSUE ONE BUT DOES NOT GIVE A CONCATENATED CHAR*
}
```

All of this works, but then running valgrind I get

Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialized value(s) referring to the  "strcat(genome,data); "

and Uninitialized value was created by a heap allocation referring to
"char* genome = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (genome_size+chr_total));"

Based on other StackOverflow answers I tried sprintf(&genome[strlen(genome)],data); and sprintf(genome+strlen(genome),data); instead of strcat. However they too gives the same valgrind message.

The only thing that seems to alleviate this error is using sprintf(genome,data); however then i will not get the full genome but just a single chromosome.

Trying genome += sprintf(genome,data); gives me ./a.out': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: and ./a.out': free()

In regards to the "Uninitialized value was created by a heap allocation" error -> then my issue is that I am only able to free that memory after all of the threads are done running. So I am not sure how to initialize the values in the heap allocation when I am using malloc.

Is it possible to solve some of these specific valgrind errors?

Comment: `strcat(genome,data);` The first error is because `strcat` requires valid C strings for both parameters. An uninitialised buffer like `genome` contains random garbage and is not a valid C string. Init with `genome[0] = 0;` after  `malloc`.

Comment: `genome+strlen(genome)` That has the same problem. Can't get `strlen` of an uninitalised buffer.

Comment: Do not forget to check `if (genome != NULL)` before using it. The same should be done for `data` since it is storing the return value of the function `fai_fetch()`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments!. @kiner_shah do you mean like
pthread_mutex_lock(&data_mutex);
const char *data = fai_fetch(seq_ref,chr_names[i],&chr_sizes[i]);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&data_mutex);

if (data != NULL);
sprintf(genome+strlen(genome),data);

Comment: From what I know, `strlen()` uses `NULL` character to determine end of a string. `genome` is just allocated memory from `malloc()` and it can't be sure it's memory has `NULL` characters - there can be garbage data. So, I would suggest you do a `memset(genome, '\0', genome_size + chr_total)` after doing `malloc` so as not to have any undefined behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Using Valgrind to locate the problematic code

The "*Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)*" message means Valgrind has determined that some result of your program depends on uninitialized memory.
Use the `--track-origins=yes` flag to track the origin of the uninitialized value. It might help you finding that value. From `man 1 valgrind`:

> When set to yes, Memcheck keeps track of the origins of all uninitialised values. Then, when an uninitialised value error is reported, Memcheck will try to show the origin of the value. An origin can be one of the following four places: a heap block, a stack allocation, a client request, or miscellaneous other sources (eg, a call to brk).

More specifically in your program:

## Problem 1: Using uninitialized `genome`

The line

```
char* genome = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (genome_size+chr_total));
```

Allocates the `genome` buffer using `malloc(2)` and then consumes it in:

```
strcat(genome,data);
```

Please note that functions such as `strlen(3)` and `strcat(3)` works on C-strings, which are buffers that terminate with a null character ('\0').

`malloc(2)` just allocates memory and it **doesn't** initialize it so your allocated buffer may contain **any** value (and considered as uninitialized). You should avoid using string related functions with an uninitialized buffers as it results undefined behavior.

Fortunately `calloc(2)` does the trick - it allocates the buffer and initializes all of its bits to zero, resulting a valid 0 length C-string you can operate on. I suggest the following fix to ensure that `genome` is initialized:

```cpp
char* genome = calloc(genome_size+chr_total+1, sizeof(char));
```

Also note that I've added `+1` to the length of the allocated buffer. It is done to guarantee that the resulting `genome` will end with a null terminator (assuming that `genome_size+chr_total` is the total size of all the buffers returned from `fai_fetch`).

Also note that in terms of performance `calloc` is a bit slower than `malloc` (because it initializes the data) but for my opinion it is safer as it initializes the whole buffer. For the purposes of your specific program, you could save the performance burden by using `malloc` and initializing just the first byte:

```
char* genome = malloc(sizeof(char) * (genome_size + chr_total + 1));
if (NULL == genome) {
    perror("malloc of genome failed");
    exit(1);
}
// So it will be a valid 0 length c-string
genome[0] = 0;
```

We don't have to initialize the last byte to be 0 because `strcat` writes the terminating null character for us.

## (Potential) Problem 2: Using potentially non-null terminated `data` with `strcat`

As you described in your question, the `fai_fetch` extracts some data:

```cpp
const char *data = fai_fetch(seq_ref,chr_names[i],&chr_sizes[i]);
```

and then consumes it in the `strcat` line:

```cpp
strcat(genome,data);
```

As I wrote above, because you use `strcat`, `data` should be null-terminated as well.

I'm not sure how `fai_fetch` is implemented but if it returns a valid C-string then you're all good.

If it doesn't then you should use `strncat` which works on buffers that are not null-terminated.

From `man 3 strcat`:

> The strncat() function is similar, except that
>
> - it will use at most n bytes from src; and
> - src does not need to be null-terminated if it contains n or
>   more bytes.

I suggest the following fix:

```cpp
// I'm not sure what type `&chr_sizes[i]` is, assuming it's `size_t`
size_t length = &chr_sizes[i];
const char *data = fai_fetch(seq_ref,chr_names[i], length);
// Use strcat
strncat(genome, used_data, length);
```

Comment: Thanks for a really well explained walkthrough.!

Comment: Don't use `--track-origins=yes` unless you can't figure out where the 'uninitializedness' is coming from based on the line of code where the error occurs.

Comment: @PaulFloyd Why? You've made a statement without any reasoning, please elaborate.

Comment: Mainly because it will make things around 2x slower. Of course if you want things to be as slow as possible, carry on.